# reverse linked list in between 2 indices

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I'm trying to solve this problem and there's a bug in my code, but i can't figure out why: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list-ii/description/

Given a sorted linked list, delete all nodes that have duplicate numbers, leaving only distinct numbers from the original list.

For example,
Given 1->2->3->3->4->4->5, return 1->2->5.
Given 1->1->1->2->3, return 2->3.

The error is

```
Line 44: TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of null
```

Here is the code in Javascript

```
function ListNode(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
}

var reverseBetween = function(head, m, n) {
    if(m>=n) return head;
    var currentNode = head;
    var previousNode = null;
    var temp = null, tempStart = null;
    var countm = 0, countn=0;
    if(!currentNode.next) return head;
    var startNode = null;
    console.log([head.val, head.next.val, head.next.next.val, head.next.next.next.val, head.next.next.next.next.val]);

    while(countm<m){
        //advance pointer and do nothing
        startNode = previousNode;
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        countm++;
        console.log(previousNode.val + ', ' + currentNode.val)
    }
    console.log('before: startNode: ' + startNode.val + ', prev: ' + previousNode.val + ', curr: ' +currentNode.val)
    while(countn < (n-m)){

        temp = currentNode.next;
        currentNode.next = previousNode;
        startNode.next = currentNode;
        previousNode.next = temp;


        countn++;
        console.log('startNode: ' + startNode.val + ', prev: ' + previousNode.val + ', curr: ' +currentNode.val)
        console.log([head.val, head.next.val, head.next.next.val, head.next.next.next.val, head.next.next.next.next.val]);

        //advance
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        console.log('startNode: ' + startNode.val + ', prev: ' + previousNode.val + ', curr: ' +currentNode.val)
    }

    return head;
};

var a = new ListNode(1);
var b = new ListNode(2);
var c = new ListNode(3);
var d = new ListNode(4);
var e = new ListNode(5);
a.next = b;
b.next = c;
c.next = d;
d.next = e;

reverseBetween(a, 2, 4)
```

Comment: Can you provide an example linked list that you use?

Comment: I updated the code to call the linked list at the bottom @Skyler

Comment: OK finally got this! I needed to save a second pointer rather than using `currentNode` to advance

Answer (score 1):

```
function ListNode(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
}

var reverseBetween = function(head, m, n) {
    if(m>=n) return head;
    var currentNode = head;
    var previousNode = null;
    var temp = null, tempStart = null;
    var countm = 0, countn=0;
    if(!currentNode.next) return head;
    var startNode = null;
    console.log([head.val, head.next.val, head.next.next.val, head.next.next.next.val, head.next.next.next.next.val]);

    while(countm<m){
        //advance pointer and do nothing
        startNode = previousNode;
        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        countm++;
        console.log(previousNode.val + ', ' + currentNode.val)
    }
    console.log('before: startNode: ' + startNode.val + ', prev: ' + previousNode.val + ', curr: ' +currentNode.val)
    while(countn < (n-m)){

        temp = currentNode.next;
        temp2 = previousNode;
        currentNode.next = previousNode;
        startNode.next = currentNode;
        previousNode.next = temp;


        countn++;
        console.log('startNode: ' + startNode.val + ', prev: ' + previousNode.val + ', curr: ' +currentNode.val)
        console.log([head.val, head.next.val, head.next.next.val, head.next.next.next.val, head.next.next.next.next.val]);

        //advance
        previousNode = temp2;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        console.log('startNode: ' + startNode.val + ', prev: ' + previousNode.val + ', curr: ' +currentNode.val)
    }

    return head;
};

var a = new ListNode(1);
var b = new ListNode(2);
var c = new ListNode(3);
var d = new ListNode(4);
var e = new ListNode(5);
a.next = b;
b.next = c;
c.next = d;
d.next = e;

reverseBetween(a, 2, 4)
```